# Max image units in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to define this `image2D` variable in my compute shader, in order to store some data needed for future rendering:

```
layout ( binding = 8, rgba32f) writeonly uniform image2D MyTexture ;
```

However, this somehow seems not be able to work, since when I compile this shader, it gives me the following error information:

```
Error: image binding must be less than "GL_MAX_IMAGE_UNITS" (8)
```

I did already defined 8 `image2D` textures in previous codes. It seems like there are not enough `GL_IMAGE_UNIT` slots on my graphics card (I'm actually using a core graphics card **Intel(R) HD Graphics 620** on my computer). How I'm I supposed to fix this? Are there any way to avoid using the 8th image unit? Or I have to move to another computer to finish my work, which will be really troublesome :(

Comment: You can't, You only have 8 image units. Do you really need 9 different images in one shader?

Comment: yeah... actually I have several shaders (all compute shader), and I need 9 different images in total. Is the max number of images related to hardware? And do I have any ways to avoid using so many images? Many thanks :)

Comment: Can you use one `image2DArray` instead of multiple `image2D`?

Comment: @Rabbid76 by using `image2DArray`, does it add counting to `GL_MAX_IMAGE_UNITS`?

Comment: For an `image2DArray` you need 1 image unit. The `image2DArray` can contain multiple layers of 2D images of the same size and format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one `image2DArray` instead of multiple `image2D`. For an `image2DArray` you need 1 image unit. The `image2DArray` can contain multiple layers of 2D images of the same size and format. Therefore, you can reduce the number of image units used by bundling multiple two-dimensional images into a two-dimensional image array.